# Applying Minimax Algorithm to Decision tree stored as an Array, Python

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I am trying to create a game of Tic-Tac-Toe which allows the user to play against the program. The program is to use the Minimax algorithm to prune a decision tree and output the optimal move. Below I have posted the code to where I am developing the class of the Game Ai. The function "create_tree" returns a decision tree of all the possible moves from the root node and the depth at which the states would occur. I have tried to pass this through a module that applies the minimax pruning method to find the next optimal moves that should be made however it is not working, as when I try and evaluate a game state, IDLE throws up the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Faisal\Documents\Python\Comp4 project\class_test3.py", line
>   87, in 
>       print(node.minimax())   File "C:\Users\Faisal\Documents\Python\Comp4 project\class_test3.py", line
>   56, in minimax
>       if self.check_if_won(node[each])== 1: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

My code is below:

```
Board = ['X', 'X', 3, 'O', 5, 'X', 7, 'O', 9]
whose_move = 1

depth = 0 
class Node():
    def __init__(self, Board, whose_move):
        self.Board = Board
        self.whose_move = whose_move
        self.win_comb = ((0,1,2), (3,4,5), (6,7,8), (6,3,0), (7,4,1), (8,5,2), (6,4,2), (8,4,0))
        self.piece = 'X'
        self.depth = depth

   def create_tree(self,piece=None,Board=None):
        if Board is None:
            Board = self.Board
            depth = self.depth
        if piece is None:
            piece = self.piece
        child_nodes = []
        for index, square in enumerate(Board):
            if square == index + 1:  # if square not taken
                new_board = Board[:]  # make a shallow copy
                new_board[index] = piece
                child_nodes.append(new_board)
                if self.check_if_won(new_board) == -1:   # removed self in arguments
                    if piece == 'X':
                        child_nodes.append(self.create_tree('O',new_board))
                    else:
                        child_nodes.append(self.create_tree('X',new_board))
        return [child_nodes]


    def check_if_won(self,Board=None):
        for each in self.win_comb:
            if (Board[each[0]] == Board[each[1]] and Board[each[1]]== Board[each[2]]):
                return 1
        for index,square in enumerate(Board):
            if square == index + 1:
                return -1
        return 0

    def who_won(Board=None):
        for each in self.win_comb:
            if(Board[each[0]]) == 'X':
               return 1
            else:
               return 0

    def minimax(self,node=None,player=None):
        best= None
        if node == None:
            node = self.create_tree()
        if player == None:
            player = 'X'
        for each in node:
                if self.check_if_won(node[each])== 1:
                    if self.who_won(node[each]) == 1:
                        return 1
                    elif self.who_won(node[each]) == 0:
                       return -1
                elif self.check_if_won(node[each]) == 0:
                       return 0
        for move in node:
            if player == 'X':
                val = self.minimax(node,'O')
            else:
                val = self.minimax(node,'X')
            if player == 'X':
                if val > best:
                    best = val
            else:
                if val<best:
                    best = val
        return best






node = Node(Board, whose_move)

n = node.create_tree()

print(n)

print(node.minimax())
```

When I run the program my create_tree() module generates the following output

```
[[['X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 5, 'X', 7, 'O', 9], ['X', 'X', 3, 'O', 'X', 'X', 7, 'O', 9], [[['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 7, 'O', 9], [[['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 9], [[['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O']]], ['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 7, 'O', 'X']]], ['X', 'X', 3, 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 9], [[['X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 9], ['X', 'X', 3, 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X']]], ['X', 'X', 3, 'O', 'X', 'X', 7, 'O', 'O'], [[['X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 7, 'O', 'O'], ['X', 'X', 3, 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O'], [[['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O']]]]]]], ['X', 'X', 3, 'O', 5, 'X', 'X', 'O', 9], [[['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 5, 'X', 'X', 'O', 9], [[['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 9], [[['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O']]], ['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 5, 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X'], [[['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X']]]]], ['X', 'X', 3, 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 9], [[['X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 9], ['X', 'X', 3, 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X'], [[['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X']]]]]...
```

And so it is understandable as to why the error is produced however I don't know how to extract each game state at different depths of the tree in a systematic order.

Comment: "is not working" explain more please!

Comment: @Arman When the program is run I get the Error Message val = self.minimax(node,'O')and val = self.minimax(node,'X')

Comment: Please explain full trackback

Comment: @Arman I have edited the post to clarify my problems and added a full traceback of the errors

Comment: I think you should  try `self.check_if_won(each)==` because you iterate over `node` list

Comment: @Arman The error is still thrown up